# Scale canvas without scaling image inside the canvas

Tags: c#, wpf, image, canvas, graphics

I have an image on a canvas, and I set the size of the canvas to the size of the image (I want the canvas as small as it needs to be). Now I want to apply a drop-shadow effect on the image, but some parts get clipped because they are outside the canvas. So I need to increase the canvas without scaling the image.

I was able to manually scale the image down, which works but I would rather not touch the image and instead increase the canvas size.

Here is what I tried, but the image scales with the canvas.

```
<Canvas ClipToBounds="True" Name="ImageDropShadowThumbnail" Height="{Binding Height}" Width="{Binding Width}">
    <Canvas.LayoutTransform>
        <ScaleTransform ScaleX="{Binding Value, ElementName=ScaleXSlider}" ScaleY="{Binding Value, ElementName=ScaleYSlider}" CenterX="{Binding CenterX}" CenterY="{Binding CenterY}"/>
    </Canvas.LayoutTransform>
    <Image Source="{Binding Name}" Height="{Binding Height}" Width="{Binding Width}" Stretch="None" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <Image.Effect>
            <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="{Binding Value, ElementName=BlurRadiusSlider}" Direction="{Binding Value, ElementName=DirectionSlider}" Opacity="{Binding Value, ElementName=OpacitySlider}" ShadowDepth="{Binding Value, ElementName=ShadowDepthSlider}"/>
        </Image.Effect>
    </Image>

</Canvas>
```

Comment: Add Converter to Canvas Width and Height binding to Image size and in converter add some space + 30 for instance so that dropshadoweffect would be visible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 <Canvas Background="CadetBlue" Width="{Binding ElementName=Image1, Path=Width, Converter={StaticResource HeightConverter}}"
        Height="{Binding ElementName=Image1, Path=Height, Converter={StaticResource HeightConverter}}">
    <Image Name="Image1" Source="1.jpg" Width="150" Height="150" Stretch="Fill"/>
</Canvas>

 [ValueConversion(typeof(double), typeof(double))]
public class HeightConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        double result;
        Double.TryParse(value.ToString(), out result);
        return result + 20.0;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Because you put it in canvas it will be placed by default in left top corner so need to set Canvas.Left/Top etc.